# Android - populating database column with random values

Tags: android, database, random, populate

I am trying to populate a database column with random values like this, it works in sql (each row get a different random value)

```
UPDATE vyroky SET poradie = RANDOM();
```

However when I try to do this with a content resolver and provider, it just inserts 0 for some reason

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(QuoteContentProvider.COLUMN_ORDER, "RANDOM()");
int count = getContentResolver().update(QuoteContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, null, null);
```

Thanks !

Comment: I think you have to generate the number in Java and pass it in to that function.  "RANDOM()" as a value isn't executing the RANDOM function.

Comment: It has worked when I used it in db.query() inside ContentProvider.onCreate, however content provider gets instantiated and persists even though activity died, so it gets called only once. I need to randomize this everytime app is started.